# The parameter to the function is required but was not passed in

Tags: ajax, coldfusion, multi-select, cfml

I am making a filter in order to drill down into a report. I have two fields that are dependent on the selection of another field (which is a multiselect list).  When I make my selection(s) from that multiselect field, it looks like the parameter is being passed in as an array and ultimately not being recognized.  It looks as if my parameter is being passed in as an array, which I'm thinking is the issue

[image: Browser Debug Screen]

**Javascript Code:**

```
function getMO()
{
    var fa_code = $('#tslcFilterFA').val();
    var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').val();
    var wq_code = $('#tslcFilterWQ').val();
    var newOption = '';
    $('#tslcFilterMO').empty();
    $('#tslcFilterMO').append(newOption);
    $('#TSLC_MO_Loading').css('display','inline');

    $.ajax({
        url: '../TSLC/getData.cfc',
        type:"POST",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "text",
        async:true,
        data: {method: "getMO",
            fa_code: fa_code,
            ao_code: ao_code,
            wq_code: wq_code
       },
      success: function(returnMsg)
          {

                try
                {
                    var obj = JSON.parse(returnMsg);
                    $.each(obj.DATA, function(index,row) {
                        if (obj.DATA.length == 1)
                        {
                            var newOption = '<option selected="selected" value="' + row[0] + '">' + row[1] + '</option>';
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (row[2] == "1")
                            {
                                var newOption = '<option selected="selected" value="' + row[0] + '">' + row[1] + '</option>';
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var newOption = '<option value="' + row[0] + '">' + row[1] + '</option>';
                            }


                        }

                        $('#tslcFilterMO').append(newOption);


                    });
                    try
                    {
                        $('#tslcFilterMO').multiselect('destroy');
                    }
                    catch(e) {}
                    $('#tslcFilterMO').multiselect({
                        selectedList: 4
                        }).multiselectfilter();
                    $('.ui-multiselect').css('width','225px');
                    $('#TSLC_MO_Loading').css('display','none');

                }
                catch(e)
                {
                  alert('getMO Error parsing JSON');
                }



          },
        error: function(httpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown)
               {
                    alert("getMO status=" + textStatus + ",error=" + errorThrown);
             }
        });
    }
```

I've tried to change this line:

```
var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').val();
```

to this:

```
var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').multiselect('getChecked').map(function () {return this.value;}).get();
```

I've also tried to wrap my `ao_code` variable in `URLDecode()` to see if it would pass the value as a string instead of an array, but neither works.

**CF Code (from component):**

```
<cffunction name="getMO" access="remote" returntype="any" returnformat="plain" hint="Get distinct Managing Orgs based on FA=ATT_IT and AO">
    <cfargument name="fa_code" type="string" required="true">
    <cfargument name="ao_code" required="true">
    <cfargument name="wq_code" required="true">

    <cfquery name="qMO" datasource="#request.dbdsn_ic4p#" username="#request.dbuser_m66266#" password="#request.dbpw_m66266#">
         SELECT DISTINCT managing_org MANAGING_ORG, DECODE(managing_org,'*','*ALL*',managing_org) MANAGING_ORG_DISPLAY, DECODE(managing_org,'*',1,2) sortcol
        <cfif #fa_code# NEQ "ATT_IT">
             FROM HAS_TICKET_STATE_GUI_LOOKUP
             WHERE client_id = '#fa_code#'
        <cfelse>
            FROM IT_TICKET_STATE_GUI_LOOKUP
            WHERE 1=1
        </cfif>
        <cfif #ao_code# neq "">
            AND active_org IN (<cfqueryparam value="#ao_code#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_varchar" list="true" />)
        </cfif>
        <cfif #wq_code# neq "">
            <!--- !COM: is workaround for commas in listbox items! --->
            AND work_queue IN (#replace(ListQualify(wq_code,"'",",","CHAR"),":COM!",",","all")#)
        </cfif>
        ORDER BY 3, 1
    </cfquery>

    <cfreturn serializeJson(qMO)>
</cffunction>
```

Comment: Not related to your question, but the cfqueryparam tag used for active_org would work equally well for work_queue.

Comment: traditional option maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change this line in your JS code

```
var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').val();
```

to

```
var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').val().join(",");
```

That should give you a list of string values from the multiple select field that you're expecting in your function in the CFC.

The `join()` method joins all elements of an array into a string. [More on "join" here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

Comment: Though if the data itself contains commas, you should use a different delimiter with both join() and cfqueryparam.

Answer (score 0):

This article helped me solve my problem... https://christierney.com/2011/06/07/returning-multiple-value-elements-to-coldfusion-remote-method-via-jquery-ajax/

```
function getWQ()
{
var fa_code = $('#tslcFilterFA').val();
var ao_code = $('#tslcFilterAO').val();
if ($.isArray(ao_code))
    var ao_code_array = ao_code.join(",");
else
    var ao_code_array = ao_code;
var mo_code = $('#tslcFilterMO').val();
if ($.isArray(mo_code))
    var mo_code_array = mo_code.join(",");
else
    var mo_code_array = mo_code;
var newOption = '';
$('#tslcFilterWQ').empty();
$('#tslcFilterWQ').append(newOption);
$('#TSLC_WQ_Loading').css('display','inline');

$.ajax({
    url: '../TSLC/cfcs/getData.cfc',
    type:"POST",
    cache: false,
    dataType: "text",
    async:true,
    data: {method: "getWQ",
        fa_code: fa_code,
        mo_code: mo_code_array,
        ao_code: ao_code_array
   },
   success: function(returnMsg)
   {
```

Comment: Should your link ever fail you should provide comments in your code to explain why and how this will answer the OP's question.

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered a combination of the jQuery [serializeArray()](https://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) function and the [param()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) function?  It creates a string similar to a query string which is easily parsed.  You could send the whole form in.

Example: $.param($('#yourform').serializeArray(),false);

Or, perhaps, simply use the serializeArray function to send your function a JSON string?